large insert into database in pyhton
I need to create a routine that inserts 600 thousand rows into the database, but I can't get performance with Python, even paginating the API and inserting in parts
insert_values = [tuple(row) for _, row in df.iterrows()]
        
        try:
            cursor.executemany(insert_query, insert_values)
            conection.commit()
            print(f'Dados da página {current_page} inseridos sucesso.')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Erro ao inserir dados em lote: {e}")
            print("Tentando inserir linha por linha para identificar o problema...")

            for row in insert_values:
                try:
                    cursor.execute(insert_query, row)
                    conection.commit()

                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Erro na linha {row}: {e}")

I need to insert at least 50 thousand lines in the shortest possible time

I’m not sure why this was graduated from the Staging Ground without having the major feedback addressed in any meaningful or material way. That said: it would be helpful to include more specific information about how this code performs currently (with specific time measurements) and how much more performant from that measurement you require.

What does the database itself look like? What DBMS is it? Where is it hosted in relation to the machine where this code is being executed? Can you [edit] your question with this pertinent info?

Also, a demonstration that better performance is possible in some non-Python language is an essential part of the problem. It's not a Python problem if it's also slow in every other language. (Profiling to show whether time is being spent waiting for the database to complete operations or in overhead within the Python interpreter itself is another way to come at that side of the issue).

"....a routine that inserts 600 thousand rows"  vs. "I need to insert at least 50 thousand lines"    ????  What do, you think, you need to do ?
